# Why is the destructor in Delphi named?

Tags: delphi, destructor

Destructors in Delphi are usually named "Destroy", however as far as i understand you can also

- name destructors differently
- have multiple destructors

Is there any reason why this was implemented this way? What are the possible use cases for differently named / multiple destructors?

Comment: Most likely this was for consistency. But I've never seen a scenario where you do anything other than override the virtual Destroy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory you can manually call different destructors to free different external resources, like breaking ref-counting loops, deleting or just closing file, etc.

Also, since the Object Pascal language does not have those magical new/delete operations, there just should be some identifier to call for disposing of the object.

I'd prefer to look at that in retrospect.

"Turbo Pascal with Objects" style objects have both - you call a "magical" `Dispose` procedure but explicitly specify a destructor to call, since language itself did not knew what to choose. Similarly "magic" procedure `New` had to be supplied with a manually selected constructor.

- http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/dispose.html
- http://putka.acm.si/langref/turboPascal/0547.html
- http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/new.html
- http://putka.acm.si/langref/turboPascal/04A4.html

This however violates DRY principle: compiler knows that we are calling d-tor or c-tor, but yet we have to additionally call those "New" and "Dispose" functions. In theory that probably provided to decouple memory allocation and information feeding and combine them anyway we'd like. But i don't think this feature was actually used anything wide.

*Interesting that the same design is used in Apple Objective C. You 1st allocate memory for the object and after that you call a constructor for that new instance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Instantiation*

When that model was streamlined for Delphi few decisions was made to make things more simplified (and unified). Memory [de]allocation strategy was shifted to the class level, rather than call-site. That made the redundancy of both calling "New" and named constructor very contrast. One had to be dropped.

C++/C#/Java chosen to retain a special language-level keywords for it, using overloaded functions to provide different c-tors. Perhaps that corresponds to USA style of computer languages.

However Pascal at its core has two ideas: verbosity and small vocabulary. Arguably they can be tracked in other European-school languages like Scala. If possible, the keywords should be removed from language itself and moved to external modules - libraries that you can add or remove from project. And overloaded functions were introduced much later to the language and early preference was to surely have two differently named (self-documenting) function names.

This both ideas probably caused Delphi to remove "magic" procedures and to deduce object creation/destruction at the call-site just by used function names. If you call `MyVar.Destroy` then compiler looks at the declaration of `.Destroy` and knows we are deleting the object. Similarly it knows `TMyType.CreateXXX(YYY,ZZZ)` is an object instanbtiation due to the way `CreateXXX` was declared.

To make c-tor and d-tor no-named like in C++, Delphi would have to introduce two more keywords to the language level, like those C++ `new` and `delete`. And there seems to be no clear advantage in that. At least personally i better like Delphi way.

PS. I had to add there one assumption: we are talking about real C++ and Delphi languages as they were around 1995. They only featured manual memory control for heap-allocated objects, no garbage collection and no automatic ref-counting. You could not trigger object destruction by assigning variable with nil/NULL pointer.

Comment: Final paragraph is too strong. It could perfectly be done without keyword support. What's more C++ constructors and destructors are named.

Comment: named? So i can have class `CMyClass` with a constructor `ABetterNameIKnow` ? How ? And how you would do it without keywords and without named constructors ?

Comment: Constructors of that class are named CMyClass::CMyClass.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that means they are not named. Naming is when i am naming according to my choice. That is exactly that kind of naming, as naming of `begin` or `while` keywords. They are identifiers too so they are named like in your example. Just their scope is a bit wider than the scope of :CMyClass.

Comment: I think that C++ constructors are named. If they weren't named, how would the compiler know how to find them. We are talking at cross purposes it seems. I know what you mean. I just find the terminology you used confusing.

Comment: I think they are de facto local-scope keywords because you have absolutely no control over them. you may also say "for" and "int" are named because otherwise "how would the compiler know how" to treat them. "Naming" is where someone is giving names, someone who is subject, that is the programmer. If the programmer cannot give the name - then that is de facto local scope keywords. Same holds for `break`, `continue`, `exit`/`return`, etc. The topic is of language design, so it the 1st step is the essence, the "geist" of the language. Later that concept would be formalized, but that is later

Comment: I still disagree with your statement in the final paragraph. Please prove that it is not possible to implement ctor/dtor without new language keyword.

Comment: Show me example how it "could perfectly be done without keyword support" in a practical language. The omission that i made yesterday - manual memory control, there is was no ARC or GC in Delphi or C++. Now, we have to make an expression which evaluation would trigger the destruction of any given, unknown in advance, object. `var o: TObject;` - how can i dispose of it without having any kind of identifier  dedicated to it ? Neither language-level operation nor RTL-level fixed method name ?

Comment: Fixed method name would be fine. But you said keyword. That's all I am objecting to.

Comment: Okay, you seem to think that keyword is something with global scope and maybe some additional qualities. I think that keyword is some ID you have no control upon inside its scope. Is there a term exactly for a predefined non-alterable identifier regardless of its scope, so both method names and keywords like "while" would fit it?